# need a real map

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

is there anyone can give me a real map produced by gmapping or other technique?
by 'real', i mean a real map generated by a robot or similar algorithm, complete with noise,inaccuracies,etc.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/60719/need-a-real-map/) by [unknown](https://answers.ros.org/users/4599/unknown/) on ROS Answers with karma: 15 on 2013-04-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Some of the maps we use are available:

- http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Ftidyup_robot-experimental%2Ftidyup_launch_geb78_191112%2Fmaps
- http://code.google.com/p/alufr-ros-pkg/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2Ftidyup_robot%2Ftidyup_executive%2Fmaps
- https://github.com/GKIFreiburg/gki_data/tree/master/gki_maps/fr_052/maps

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You'll find several maps of Willow Garage in this package: http://ros.org/wiki/willow_maps

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2013-04-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [unknown](https://answers.ros.org/users/4599/unknown/) on 2013-04-15**:
can you write more details about it? how can i get the package?